# Backbone.js form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've been watching backbone.js tutorials, but I'm still confused on how I can save form data into a new object to be later saved into a database.

So basically I have a dynamically generated form called "true / false" that the user fills out to generate a true or false question. For now, on submit, I need to save that form data to an object. Hope that makes sense. Right now it's only displaying one attribute in the console.log, but what I need is the edited attributes plus default values, defined in the code. Any advice / help is greatly appreciated, and yes I have RTFM

```
(function() {
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {}
};

App.Models.TestTypes = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

App.Collections.TestTypes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.TestTypes
});

App.Views.TestTypes = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('div.add-btn'),

    events: {
        'click button.btn-add-tf' : 'addTrueFalse',
        'click button.btn-add-mult' : 'addMult',
        'click button.btn-add-short' : 'addShort',
        'click button.btn-add-essay' : 'addEssay'
    },
    // event handling functions

    addTrueFalse: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.addTrueFalseForm();
        this.addTrueFalsePreview();
    },

    addTrueFalseForm: function(e) {
        $('.new-questions').append('<div class="add-question"><form action="">' +
            '<div class="remove-btn">x</div>' +
            '<span style="font-weight: normal;;"><em>True / False</em></span></p>' +
            '<label for="Question_description">Question</label><br />' +
            '<input type="text" name="question[description]" class="tf-desc" /><br />' +
            'True <input type="radio" name="question_answer[answer]" id="question_answer[correct]" value="1" />' +
            ' False <input type="radio" name="question_answer[answer]" id="question_answer[correct]" value="0" /><br />' +
            '<input type="submit" value="Save" /></form>' +
            '</div>');
    },

    addTrueFalsePreview: function(e) {
        $('#test-preview').append("<p>Preview</p>");
    }
});

App.Views.NewTestType = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.new-questions',

    events: {
        'submit': 'addTest'
    },

    addTest: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var addTestData = $(e.currentTarget).find('.tf-desc').val();

        var task = new App.Models.TestTypes({ description: addTestData });
        this.collection.add(task);
        console.log(task);
    }

});

var testTypesCollection = new App.Collections.TestTypes([
    {
        defaults: {
            questions: 0,
            type: "",
            description: "",
            require_review: 0,
            max_points: 0,
            is_bonus: 0,
            order: 0,
            case_sensitive: 0,
            answer: "",
            points: 0,
            is_correct: 0
        }

    }]);

var addTest = new App.Views.NewTestType({ collection: testTypesCollection });
var question = new App.Views.TestTypes({ collection: testTypesCollection });

})();
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the form data around on the client? It's not clear yet what the relationship to the form would be to a model or collection you would be using. You can always just make a direct ajax call from your view on form submission if you don't need to put that form data into your client-side model.

Comment: Yes. The form data is for creating an exam, and I think a feature that allows the exam to be viewed as it's created will be really beneficial to my users because not all of them will be tech-savvy. What I'm going for is similar to Stripes API documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api

Comment: an old prototype before I tried backbone. This is what I'm going for: http://jsfiddle.net/visevo/BxgSG/

Comment: Ah, so the data you're storing is the question, question type, etc? If so, then it seems like you want your collection to be a collection of questions, and you need a model with attributes to capture the question, question type, etc. Does that sound like what you're trying to do?

Comment: yeah that sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do. I have a php background, not javascript so this aspect of the project is becoming exceedingly difficult. can you point me in the right direction? books, articles, hints, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use [Backbone.Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/)'s CompositeView/CollectionView and ItemView to accomplish what you have in mind.

And it will be easier for you if you are using one of the PHP restful frameworks to work with Backbone.